# What is causing this disk I/O spike?

Tags: io, sbuild, iotop

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed and I'm experiencing a strange problem. I'm attempting to use `sbuild` to build a Debian package and everything works well enough for the first few seconds...

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/tmp/pkg/pkg-0.0.1$ sbuild
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
...
```

However, `sbuild` runs into some issues while attempting to install some of the packages:

```
...
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:armhf (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) over (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
```

It stops at this point and the disk I/O LED becomes saturated.

I had two other terminal windows open with `top` and `iotop` running. According to `top`, the CPU and memory usage is as follows:

```
%Cpu(s):  4.7 us,  1.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 70.2 id, 23.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:    946112 total,   657852 used,   288260 free,    41276 buffers
```

According to `iotop`:

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
```

Nothing seems to be reaching its limit. None of the mounted partitions are more than 31% full.

What could possibly cause this anomaly and what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Note: I tried this twice more and was able to reproduce it only one of those times. Seems to be a sporadic issue.